# Аналог функции wait() для phpbrowser (не работает функция wait)

Tags: php, codeception

Использую связку codeception + PhpBrowser
Мне необходимо чтобы между шагами теста проходило определенное кол-во времени (0.6 сек).
Способ, предлагаемый в официальной документации
`$I -> wait (3);`
подходит только для WebDriver
существует ли аналог данной функции для phpbrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет php функции `sleep(3)` ?
Если нужно будет float значение, то `usleep(0.3)`

Не уверен что это поможет, но попробовать стоит